# Wildfly logging to file issue

Tags: java, logging, log4j, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly, JSF, Spring, Hibernate and trying to configure logging in my application. The logging to console is working fine, but logging to file ins't working. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

**log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>

  <appender name="LOG-ALL-APPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false"/>
        <param name="file" value="all.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%5p] %c %m at %l%n"/>
        </layout>
  </appender>


  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%5p] %m at %l%n"/>
        </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LOG-ALL-APPENDER"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The file all.log is empty at all times.

Answer (score 0):

You're `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is incorrect. There is no `org.apache.log4j` subsystem. If you're attempting to exclude the logging subsystem you need to use `logging` for the subsystem name.

Have a look at the [per-logging deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-PerdeploymentLogging) documentation. I'd recommend you don't use the console appender though. It can result in [deadlocks](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-478) during shutdown.

Note that if you use the per-logging deployment configuration or exclude the logging subsystem you will not see server logging in your `all.log`.